# Php date function -1 month issue

Tags: php, date

I have previously searched for a way to remove a month from the current time and I came up with this line:

```
date("Ym",strtotime("-1 month", mktime()));
```

To be honest it worked until today, March 31st 2014. In my application these two operations return the same value (201403):

```
date("Ym",strtotime("-0 month", mktime()));
date("Ym",strtotime("-1 month", mktime()));
```

Can anyone explain to me why I have this error, and how can I fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: What does "one month" mean exactly? What result would you expect?

Comment: What I want to do is remove 1 month from my current date. It means that I will have for instance 201402 when we are in march and 201401 when we are in february.

Comment: Always reset your date to the first of the month before doing math like this on it

Comment: Then you should explicitly decrement the month number. What you're doing is subtract "one month" from "March 31st", which by definition is a pretty undefined operation.

Comment: Ok I will set it to first day of the month, then substract one month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting the date at the first day of the month before doing math on it is important! This operation allows to set the date to the first of the month :`date('01-m-Y')`. Here is the full solution of the problem:

```
date("Ym", strtotime("-1 month", strtotime(date('01-m-Y'))))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
date(
    'Ym',
    mktime(1,2,3,date('m')-1,date('d'),date('Y'))
);
```

Comment: It looks fine to me, but I still have the same problem. Unfortunatly date('Ym', mktime(1,2,3,date('m')-1,date('d'),date('Y'))) == date('Ym', mktime(1,2,3,date('m')-0,date('d'),date('Y')))